# Constructing a field extension (or Galois group) from the set of split primes

Tags: galois-theory, algebraic-number-theory

I know of certain techniques which tell you what primes split (completely) in certain field extensions, whether that be class field theory or by the theory of elliptic curves (modularity or complex multiplication).

On the other hand, if we are given a set of primes which split completely, could we construct a field extension? For example, if we have the set of primes $\{p\mid p\equiv1\pmod{m}\}$ then the cyclotomic extension $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_m)$ is the field attached to this "splitting set" of primes.

Since a field is completely determined by its set of split primes, could we theoretically create functors in both directions? Of course, the first direction, fields to split-sets-of-primes, is still "unsolved" in most cases (and the construction of non-abelian reciprocity laws is tied to the massive Langlands program) but has anyone explored the other direction, split-sets-of-primes to fields?

Any papers or references would be much appreciated. If this is an impossible task, then please explain to me how (even though I can see why it would be extremely difficult).

Comment: A Galois extension is determined by its split primes, but not the non-Galois ones https://mathoverflow.net/a/80439/84768 and generating most sets of primes which are the set of split primes of some number field is quite the non-abelian generalization of class field theory